# Sublime Text won't output Java println statements in main method

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, javac, sublime-build

**my Sublime Text javac build settings don't work for outputs like System.out.println statements in the main method.**

I am using this sublime-build (javac):

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${file_path}}",

    "variants": [

        { 
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["java", "$file_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "env": {"CLASSPATH": "/path/to/jar/files:/path/to/more/jars"}
        }
    ]

}
```

Changing "cmd" to

```
"cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""]
```

won't work either. But it compiles correctly and has a correct output on my bash command line.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it:

That's the magic line missing:

```
"cmd": ["sh", "-c", "javac $file_base_name.java && java $file_base_name"],
```